# Unable to disable generation of empty JAR (maven-jar-plugin)

Tags: maven, maven-jar-plugin

Sometimes, my Talend Open Studio components have resources but not Java sources (they are purely metadata components). I need to disable the generation of JAR files in such a case.

I configured the maven-jar-plugin this way:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <forceCreation>false</forceCreation>
            <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
            <useDefaultManifestFile>false</useDefaultManifestFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

but I still get the ${project.name}.jar file with pom.properties, pom.cml, the manifest and an empty file App.class containing only "class {}"

While I can disable the includes of all maven stuff using this:

```
<archive>
<addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
</archive>
```

I still get a JAR with the manifest file inside it

Are there some configuration parameters I misconfigured?

Comment: Change the packaging type into something different than jar but based on the snippet of your pom i'm not sure if this would work well.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea, since for those components that have a src dir, a standard JAR file must be packaged actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, even if it's only a workaround. I delete the JAR using a delete antrun task if /src/main/java directory doesn't exist:

```
<!-- remove the empty JAR if not needed -->
<if>
    <not><available file="${basedir}/src/main/java" type="dir" /></not>
    <then>
    <delete file="${project.build.directory}/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

this task requires antcontrib to work properly and, ofc, it doesn't work if you plan to do releases with maven (but it's ok for metadata-only components, like Talend Open Studio plugins)

Comment: I assume this will fail if you do releases via Maven.

Comment: yep, but a Talend component release is only a copypaste of some files in a target folder.

Comment: IMHO you should rather use `artifactId` not `name` : `<delete file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"/>`

Comment: or, even better, just `finalName` : `<delete file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>‌` - yes this is the correct one, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#finalName

Answer (score 10):

Most efficient way to disable the creation of jars is to configure the `maven-jar-plugin` like this:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-jar</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

It will place the default jar creation in the `none` phase, it will never be run.

Comment: It's surely the most elegant way to do so. But I need to disable the jar creation conditionally (ie. only if /src/main/java doesn't exist)

Comment: If you do "mvn install" this will fail with an error "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) on project xxx: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact"

Comment: This fixed it for me:   `<plugin>  
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>  
    <executions>  
     <execution>  
      <id>default-jar</id>  
      <phase>none</phase>  
     </execution>  
    </executions>  
   </plugin>  
   <plugin>  
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>  
    <executions>  
     <execution>  
      <id>default-install</id>  
      <phase>none</phase>  
     </execution>  
    </executions>  
   </plugin>`

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct maven-jar-plugin to not generate META-INF/maven/**/pom.* files, as explained in [Maven Archiver Reference](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html).

Also, you can use its [skipIfEmpty](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#skipIfEmpty) option.

Following code combines both these *(just to have them copy-paste ready)*:

```
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
...
```

This works fine, but when you do `mvn install`, it fails due to missing project artifact.
Similar problem will probably be with `mvn deploy` and with release, but I didn't check these.

However, if you can live with antrun's delete, the property `skipIfEmpty` will probably work well for you, and is a bit more elegant. At least it does not introduce a new execution and its dependencies etc.

Comment: tnx Petr for your answer, but i noticed that with your config (it's the one I used, actually) the JAR file is still generated, with the manifest file only

Comment: strange - didn't you forget to apply the `skipIfEmpty` property ? because in my testing pom this really causes `mvn clean package` to stop creating it. Or you forgot the `clean` ? _(No offense - it just works, reproducibly, on my machine, so I can't believe :) )_

Comment: 100% sure :) maybe it's because i have a (although empty) resource dir?