# Why maven assembly create manifest if file format is rar?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Maven project with the following assembly descriptor:

```xml
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>assemby-id</id>
<formats>
    <format>rar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<files>
    <file>
        <source>${project.build.directory}/resources/file.txt</source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </file>
</files>
```

If the `format` is `rar`, I get a folder `META-INF` with a manifest file in the rar.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Probably the specification for J2EE Resource Adapter Archives mandates that?

Comment: If you need a `rar` format i would recommend to take a look at the [maven-rar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maven-assembly-plugin` [does not support](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_assembly) the `rar` archive format. Quoting the `format` documentation, the list of supported formats is:

> - "zip" - Creates a ZIP file format
> - "tar" - Creates a TAR format
> - "tar.gz" or "tgz" - Creates a gzip'd TAR format
> - "tar.bz2" or "tbz2" - Creates a bzip'd TAR format
> - "jar" - Creates a JAR format
> - "dir" - Creates an exploded directory format
> - "war" - Creates a WAR format

When the archiver encounters an unknown format, it defaults to `jar` and for this format, a `META-INF` directory is created by default.

As such, the assembly you have created is not a valid RAR file. It is in fact a JAR file.

Answer (score -1):

The [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) uses the [maven-archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver) for packaging. The maven-archiver adds a MANIFEST.MF to your package.

Update:

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098501/1309035), you may configure the maven-archiver-plugin to leave out the `DefaultImplementationEntries`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: No, test with `zip` format and you will see no META-INF is added